# Java get published external IP Address?

Tags: java, networking, ip

I have been going through so many stackoverflow answers and none answers my question accurately.

My question is, how can I get my real internet external IP Address, not the local one, but my published IP Address which other people see & connect to?

Eg : 84.110.208.20
and not. 198.168.2.101

Currently im pooling the IP Address from whatismyip.com, but that takes a few seconds to get, since i have to buffer read it.

Is there a way to do it without reading the ip from a website?

Comment: What kind of router do you have? You'll have to connect to your router, and pull the information out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a solution to your problem that you are asking for, but I tried out your solution and I'm not getting the same "few seconds" delay as you, so I decided to share my solution:

```
public static String getIp() throws IOException{
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://icanhazip.com");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
    return in.readLine();
}
```

Maybe whatismyip.com is slower, or has more information to parse?

Comment: As you see, you're using a reader to get the ip, I am asking if its possible to get the ip without using any website.

Comment: Not really. You'd have to have direct access to your firewall and query it for its external IP. This is probably not feasible.